# Bcrypt reset the hash and the passwords of the users are not good anymore each time the users POST data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a login with bcrypt.
I also made a page where users can edit their information, like their bio etc.

Each time an user edit his bio on this page the hash from bcrypt change, which is normal i suppose, but the user login back, the password is wrong...

I used the same model for mongoDb for the user when he log in and when he edit his data.

I started node.js recently so I apologize if my question is stupid,,,

The controller code with the Post :

```
app.post('/settings-user', mid.requiresLogin, function(req, res, next){

User.findById(req.session.userId, function (err, user) {

    // todo: don't forget to handle err

    if (!user) {

        return res.redirect('/edit');
    }

    // good idea to trim
    var bio = req.body.bio.trim();

    // validate
    if (!bio) { // simplified: '' is a falsey
        req.flash('error', 'One or more fields are empty');
        return res.redirect('/settings-user'); // modified
    }

    // no need for else since you are returning early ^
    user.bio = bio;


    // don't forget to save!
    user.save(function (err) {

        // todo: don't forget to handle err

        res.redirect('/settings-user/');
    });
});
});


The User model :


app.post('/settings-user', mid.requiresLogin, function(req, res, next){

User.findById(req.session.userId, function (err, user) {

    // todo: don't forget to handle err

    if (!user) {

        return res.redirect('/edit');
    }

    // good idea to trim
    var bio = req.body.bio.trim();

    // validate
    if (!bio) { // simplified: '' is a falsey
        req.flash('error', 'One or more fields are empty');
        return res.redirect('/settings-user'); // modified
    }

    // no need for else since you are returning early ^
    user.bio = bio;


    // don't forget to save!
    user.save(function (err) {

        // todo: don't forget to handle err

        res.redirect('/settings-user/');
    });
});
});
```

The User model :

```
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');


    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },

    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    bio: {
      type: String
    }



});

    // authenticate input against database documents
UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function(email, password, callback) {
  User.findOne({ email: email })
      .exec(function (error, user) {
        if (error) {
          return callback(error);
        } else if ( !user ) {
          var err = new Error('User not found.');
          err.status = 401;
          return callback(err);
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password , function(error, result) {
          if (result === true) {
            return callback(null, user);
          } else {
            return callback();
          }
        })
      });
}
// hash password before saving to database
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    user.password = hash;
    next();
  })
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

the pug file :

```
 div
      form(method='post', action='/settings-user')
        label ADD BIO 
        br
        input(type='text', name='bio', placeholder='Enter something', required='')
        input(type='submit', value='Add Bio')


  </body>
```

If anyone could help,,,
thank you!

Comment: *Each time an user edit his bio on this page the hash from bcrypt change, which is normal i suppose* - that seems like a bad idea. Presumably data from the bio is being used as salt for the bcrypt hash? The salt used in hashing passwords should stay the same (per user). There's not going to be anyway to update your hash with new salt.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so how do you think i should manage that ?... should i create a new collection for the new data of the user and one collection for the data the user gives when he registers ..?. i would like to only edit the BIO, but im not sure i did that well...